# Creating Multilevel Tables in R

Tags: r

I recently got started with **R**. I would like to carry out a log-linear analysis of a 2x2x2 table. All i have are the categories and frequencies. How do I get this data into **R**?

I know that the function `table()` can make contingency tables out of data, the thing is, I already have the contingency table. The question now is how to correctly represent it in **R**.

So far, I have the following table:

```
>g1
   c1 c2 c1 c2
a1 10 20 50 20
a2  5 40 30 25
>
```

Now, above the c1 & c2 there should be a b1 and b2. 
This is obviously not the correct format for the analyses, since b1 and b2 are not included. 
I hope this question is not stupid, but I could not find a single good answer on the net.

Comment: I think you are asking several questions in one.  The obtaining of the data is one thing internal representation is another.  Could you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: It was all about the dim. As soon as i can make the table multidimensional I should be capable of using it for a log linear analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `dim` attribute of your current table:

```
g1 <- matrix(1:8,nrow=2)
g1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8
dim(g1)<-c(2,2,2)
g1
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```